# Validate artifacts in JSON file using gradle

Tags: json, maven, parsing, gradle, artifactory

I have a JSOn file which contains some artifacts location as:

```
{
    "contract_type": "jellybean",
    "contract_version": "1.2",
    "service_id": "8349a2b2-c1f8-11e5-9912-ba0be0483c18",
    "dependencies": {
        "maven": [
            {
                "group_id": "com.org.open.Download",
                "artifact_id": "DownLoadSchema",
                "version": "1.2.0-20160122190100",
                "extension": "tgz"
            },
            {
                "group_id": "com.org.open.softwarejson",
                "artifact_id": "ApmUI",
                "version": "1.2.0-20150122190100",
                "extension": "json"
            }
             ]
    }
}
```

---

All the above artifacts are located in artifactory at location.

The requriement is to verify whether the artifacts listed in json file are present in artifactory location, and this has to be done using gradle.

I need some help with following steps:

1. How to downlaod the above json or how to get the list of artifacts without downloading the json file.
2. After json is available, how to parse and match the artifacts present in json to those present in artifactory location?